# Check if each cell range in a row contains the same value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I check in Google Sheets if each cell in a range e.g. `B2:G2` contains a word e.g. `holiday`?

Comment: across all the columns or as in one cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:G2, "holiday"))<>"", TRUE))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SUM(IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B3:G3, "holiday"))<>"", 1))=6, TRUE))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That’s brilliant! Thanks a lot!